# Apply :hover to all children of an svg group

Tags: css, svg

How do I get all the elements of an svg group to change their fill color on hover?

The example below does not work at all.  If I use `.sgroup circle:hover` only the circle under the pointer works not both.

```css
.sgroup:hover {
    fill: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
<svg width="200" height="200">
    <g class="sgroup">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" fill="pink" r="10" ></circle>
        <circle cx="150" cy="150" fill="purple" r="10" ></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below. I assume this is what you're looking for?

```css
.sgroup:hover circle {
    fill: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
<svg width="200" height="200">
    <g class="sgroup">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" fill="pink" r="10" ></circle>
        <circle cx="150" cy="150" fill="purple" r="10" ></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  What a difference a `space` makes.